# Karaf: Connection refused (Corporate Proxy but proxy is correctly configured in Karaf/Maven)

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, apache-karaf

I'm sitting behind a coorporate proxy that has its own certificate. E.g. when I want my Java runtime to be able to communicate with the outer world I need to import my "coorporate certificate" to the Java truststore e.g. with `keytool -import -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -file coorp-cert.crt`

**How do I import this certificate to Apache Karaf (4.3.0)?**

Background:
I cannot install features into Karaf. E.g. `karaf@root()> feature:repo-add ecf` results in the error `Error executing command: Connection refused: connect : [...]`. The proxy is configured correctly (tested with `maven:summary` which displays valid "HTTP Proxies" values). So I suspect the missing proxy certificate is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, although the commands `http:proxy-list` and `maven:summary` displayed the correct proxy settings, I fixed the problem by appending `-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy url> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy port>` in the line starting with `set DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS` in the `$KARAF_HOME/bin/karaf.bat` file. Alternatively one can probably set the `JAVA_OPTS` or `EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS` variables before starting karaf (haven't tested the latter, though).

The certificate apparently wasn't the problem.